# How to stop cache_field table from growing?

Tags: caching

I have a website with **LOTS** of nodes and **LOTS** comments. I have lesser space in the hosting plan and don't wont to buy more. The cache_field table of the site keeps on growing due to caching.

I disabled "Cache pages for anonymous users" in admin/config/development/performance and kept 
"Cache blocks" enabled. The current performance and load time with the current settings and after a cache clear is at an OK level. But still the cache_field grows. Same with the "Cache blocks" disabled.

Due to the size of the site I feel that caching of nodes and comment are not necessary.

How to stop cache_field table from growing?

More:

1. I'm ok with coding
2. I have a VPS with 20GB Disk, and **60% filled when cache is cleared**. Once I cleared the cache when it was **75% filled and growing (with the cached data)**.
3. Sorry for the late data I have 512MB ram.

Comment: What are the limitation of your current host? DB size, HD space, etc...

Comment: I have a VPS with 20GB Disk, and **60% filled without caching** and I once cleared the cache when it was **75% filled with the cache**.

Comment: Can't you just kick that into a memory cache? Do you have enough RAM and control to use APC or memcached?

Comment: 512MB RAM for a site with a lot of comments? Typical installation profile will easily require 128MB just to install, and then 16-32MB per uncached client. So even if your OS does not need memory at all (idealistic case) your server could possibly be crashed by mere 16 people. Have you tested actual memory usage before you decided you do not need so much caching?

Comment: @Molot Thanks a lot for the pointing out. I actually have not done testing much. I cleared the cache when there are lot of people and at that time the load time was OK. I'm waiting for more traffic and then planning to go for a VPS plan with better resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could switch that cache bin so it uses something like file cache https://drupal.org/project/filecache

Also look into using memcache as that will evict the older cache data so that memcache stays within the parameters you give it.

Also consider optimizing the database; it should help to reduce the overhead
http://dominiquedecooman.com/optimize-mysql-tables-gives-35-drop-disk-usage-drupal-7-performance-tip

Finally if you really want to disable that cache you can use the [DrupalFakeCache backend](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!cache-install.inc/class/DrupalFakeCache/7) for those cache bins
https://drupal.org/node/797346

Comment: Thanks @Mikeyton2. But It will also cache and use my remaining space. Is there a way to stop the caching?

Comment: Thanks @Mikeyton2, https://drupal.org/node/797346 seems to disable the cache. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If it's VPS, then you probably have enough control over it to use APC or memcached. Modules that may help with it:

- [APC - Alternative PHP Cache](https://drupal.org/project/apc)
- [Memcache API and Integration](https://drupal.org/project/memcache)
- [Memcache Storage](https://drupal.org/project/memcache_storage)

And probably more. But they all are based on the same philosophy:

1. Keep data in RAM, as disk access is slow
2. Have a limited amount of storage, that never can be crossed
3. If there is too much data, silently delete the least used elements

So just move cache_field bin to RAM and all your problems should be solved.

Comment: I already use [Memcache Storage](https://drupal.org/project/memcache_storage). But the cache_field is still written to the mysql database. Is there any option I forgot?